# InternalError: stream did not block host until done; was already in an error state

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model-fitting

stream did not block host until done; was already in an error state how to fix it
using tensorflow keras

```
model.compile(
optimizer="adam",
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
metrics=['acc'])    
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=5)
```

this error appears

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of image can you include full `Traceback` in your question. So that it will give more visibility on the issue. And also provide more reproducible code. Thanks!

Comment: "was already in an error state" sounds like you better reset your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the notebook fixed this issue for me. If this doesn't fix it, you can try updating the GPU drivers.
  Also, a similar issue is available on GitHub : [Link to the Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1060)